# Webpack 4 output.library failed to add object to window

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I am upgrading a project from Webpack 3 to Webpack 4.

Currently I have a file at **/my-proj/apps/myApp1/wrappers/clientWrapper.js** which is

```
export default {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
};
```

Webpack client config:

```
entry: {
  index: [
    'core-js/modules/es6.symbol',
    'regenerator-runtime/runtime',
    'core-js/fn/object/assign',
    'core-js/fn/object/values',
    'core-js/fn/object/entries',
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&path=http://0.0.0.0:3000/__webpack_hmr',
    '/my-proj/apps/myApp1/wrappers/clientWrapper.js'
  ]
},
output: {
  path: '/my-proj/build/client',
  filename: '[name].js',
  chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
  library: [ 'myApp1', '[name]' ],
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  publicPath: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/client/'
}
// ...
```

Webpack server config:

```
entry: {
  index: [
    '/my-proj/apps/myApp1/wrappers/serverWrapper.js'
  ]
},
output: {
  path: '/my-proj/build/server',
  filename: '[name].js',
  chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
  library: [ 'myApp1', '[name]' ],
  libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  publicPath: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/client/'
}
// ...
```

Since the value of `[name]` will be `index` in this case, so by Webpack's `output.library`,

the above config can help add the object to `window.myApp1.index`.

More info about this way you can check at

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32786185/2000548
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864896/2000548

The client browser console now will print

```
window.myApp1.index.default = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
}
```

The screenshot is for `window.myApp1`:

[image]

However, after upgrading to Webpack 4, with same Webpack `entry` and `output` config, it failed to add the object to `window.myApp1.index`:

```
window.myApp1.index = undefined
```

[image]

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: What properties exist on window.myApp1 if you log that?

Comment: Hi @EvanMorrison thanks for help, it only has one field which is `index`, I also added the screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I located the issue, which is caused by the new added Webpack 4's

```
optimization: {
 splitChunks: {
   chunks: 'all',
 },
},
```

which I totally forget.

Once removing them, it works again.
I will have to figure out a way later to make the app work with `splitChunks`.

If I figured out, I will post back.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be you need to add a `libraryExport` property to the webpack config's `output` object. See this reference in the docs https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibraryexport.

Comment: Thanks @EvanMorrison I tried to add `libraryExport: 'default'` to `output`. Now I got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined`, and `window.myApp1` is `{}` now. And also tried to set client or server or both's `output.libraryTarget` to `'var'` at same time according to that doc, still got same result.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. The libraryExport might need a path to the module, I might try `libraryExport: [ '[name]', 'default' ]` . If that doesn't work take a look at the output bundle and maybe that will give a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @EvanMorrison ! Still no luck. Yeah, I will further dig in.

Comment: hi @HongboMiao, any luck on this one? We are currently hitting this issue in our codebase where window cannot be assign to any object when optimization is in place.

Comment: @FranGarcía I ended up with https://stackoverflow.com/a/63162769/2000548 at that moment, basically just removing that part.

Comment: ok, thanks @HongboMiao for replying